# Why my Trie search method always returning true in Java?

Tags: java, trie

So I am doing a project which reads a text file and inserts the data of that file to Trie. And user enters a string to search, if the trie contains the word it will show the words. I did the insertion part to Trie but when I try to run the search method, all of the data is returning true. When user enters a string it prints all the data like there is no comparison. Can you guys please help me?

```
   public static boolean searchInTrie(String key){

   TrieNode current = root;
   
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        char c = key.charAt(i);
        int index= c - 'A';
        
        if (current.children[index]==null) 
            return false; 
       
        current= current.children[index];
    }

   return (current!=null)&&(current.isWord=true);
}
```

And this is the main

```
     for (String word : wordsArrayList) {
        System.out.println(searchInTrie(wordToSearch));
        searchInTrie(wordToSearch);
        if (searchInTrie(wordToSearch)==true) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `current.isWord=true` is an assignment. you probably mean `current.isWord==true` or more simply just `current.isWord`

Comment: Thats right but that didn't solve it. Still all of them returns true :(

Comment: How works the TrieNode.isWord() method?